# Raising an Exception in PL/SQL or SQL Oracle Developer within a Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures, sqlplus

im trying to handle an custom EXCEPTION in SQLPLUS, i have two stored Procedures, and I have the second stored procedure calling the first one.

In the first Stored procedure, i have a CASE thats checking the data_types of the rows in a table, and if the Type IS NOT a CHAR, VARCHAR2, DATE, or NUMBER, then its supposed to display the Data_Type and RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR of the customer EXCEPTION that i declared in the 2nd Procedure that calls the first one.

Here is my code from the 2nd stored proc:

```
 CASE CurrentRow.Data_Type 
      WHEN 'CHAR' THEN
      wDataType := (CurrentRow.Data_Type || '(' || CurrentRow.CHAR_LENGTH || ')');      
      WHEN 'VARCHAR2' THEN
      wDataType := (CurrentRow.Data_Type || '(' || CurrentRow.CHAR_LENGTH || ')');
      WHEN 'DATE' THEN
      wDataType := (CurrentRow.Data_Type);
      WHEN 'NUMBER' THEN
      wDataType := (CurrentRow.Data_Type || '(' || CurrentRow.Data_Precision || ',' || CurrentRow.Data_Scale || ')');
    ELSE
      wDataType := (CurrentRow.Data_Type);
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, '*** Unknown Data Type ' || CurrentRow.Data_Type || ' ***');      
    END CASE;
```

Now i have a nested block within my second stored proc, but no matter where i put it or try and place it around, as soon as the error is raised? it stops executing of the rest of my code, and thats my issue. I have a feeling im not doing my nested block correctly perhaps in my second stored proc...

below is the code to my second stored proc that calls my first stored proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_Tables
/*
* Sept 26th, 2021
* To process each table in the schema, and output table-related lines.
*/
AS 
  CURSOR TablesSelected IS
    SELECT Table_Name
    FROM User_Tables
    ORDER BY Table_Name ASC;
  CurrentRow User_Tables%ROWTYPE;
  dt DATE := sysdate;
  wVersionNumber VARCHAR(4) := 'V3.0';
  wLeftPadTableName VARCHAR(100);
  wLengthOfStatement VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility ' || wVersionNumber || ' ----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Run on '|| TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon DD,YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')||' at '||TO_CHAR(dt,'HH24:MI') );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- S T A R T I N G  T A B L E  D R O P S' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );

  FOR CurrentRow IN TablesSelected LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'DROP TABLE ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- T A B L E  D R O P S  C O M P L E T E D' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- S T A R T I N G  T A B L E  C R E A T E' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );

/* 
* Nested block starts
* LOOP gets all the tables in the database and aligns them up. 
*/
    DECLARE
      INVALID_COLUMN_EXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_COLUMN_EXCEPTION, -20100);
    BEGIN

  FOR CurrentRow IN TablesSelected LOOP
    wLengthOfStatement := LENGTH('CREATE TABLE' || CurrentRow.Table_Name || ' ' || '); -- ');
    wLeftPadTableName := LPAD('); -- ', wLengthOfStatement, ' ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--   Start extracting table ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATE TABLE ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name || '( ');
    Extract_Columns(CurrentRow.Table_Name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(wLeftPadTableName || 'END of table ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name || ' creation');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--' );
  END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN INVALID_COLUMN_EXCEPTION THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('================================================================================');   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('== EXCEPTION ' || SQLCODE || ' Raised - ' || SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('== Unable to complete table generation for ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('================================================================================');
    END;

/* 
* Nested block ends 
*/

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- T A B L E  C R E A T E  C O M P L E T E D' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility ' || wVersionNumber || ' ----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Run Completed on '||TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon DD,YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')||' at '||TO_CHAR(dt,'HH24:MI') );

END;
/
```

When i print out my report...my raised ERROR kills the execution of the rest of my loop, so it doesn't grab the other tables and their rows.

[image: pic1]

If any SQL wizards can help me isolate my issue i would greatly appreciate that. I need to know what I can do to make my LOOP and stored procedure CONTINUE executing even after the EXCEPTION was raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the FOR loop to continue after an EXCEPTION occurs, put the nested block inside the FOR loop.
(You also don't need a separate DECLARE for the custom EXCEPTION.)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_Tables
AS 
  CURSOR TablesSelected IS
    SELECT Table_Name
    FROM User_Tables
    ORDER BY Table_Name ASC;
  CurrentRow User_Tables%ROWTYPE;
  dt DATE := sysdate;
  wVersionNumber VARCHAR(4) := 'V3.0';
  wLeftPadTableName VARCHAR(100);
  wLengthOfStatement VARCHAR(100);
  INVALID_COLUMN_EXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_COLUMN_EXCEPTION, -20100);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility ' || wVersionNumber || ' ----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Run on '|| TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon DD,YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')||' at '||TO_CHAR(dt,'HH24:MI') );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- S T A R T I N G  T A B L E  D R O P S' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );

  FOR CurrentRow IN TablesSelected LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'DROP TABLE ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- T A B L E  D R O P S  C O M P L E T E D' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- S T A R T I N G  T A B L E  C R E A T E' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );

  FOR CurrentRow IN TablesSelected LOOP
    wLengthOfStatement := LENGTH('CREATE TABLE' || CurrentRow.Table_Name || ' ' || '); -- ');
    wLeftPadTableName := LPAD('); -- ', wLengthOfStatement, ' ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--   Start extracting table ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATE TABLE ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name || '( ');
  /* 
   * Nested block starts
   */
    BEGIN
      Extract_Columns(CurrentRow.Table_Name);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN INVALID_COLUMN_EXCEPTION THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('================================================================================');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('== EXCEPTION ' || SQLCODE || ' Raised - ' || SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('== Unable to complete table generation for ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('================================================================================');
    END;
  /*
   * Nested block ends 
   */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(wLeftPadTableName || 'END of table ' || CurrentRow.Table_Name || ' creation');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--' );
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- T A B L E  C R E A T E  C O M P L E T E D' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Oracle Catalog Extract Utility ' || wVersionNumber || ' ----' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '---- Run Completed on '||TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon DD,YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')||' at '||TO_CHAR(dt,'HH24:MI') );
END;
/
```